# Azure-DevOps display build warning

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

## Problem background

I am working on a C# project that is using Azure DevOps for CI. I have a power shell file that is being run when the project is pushed to Azure. The relevant part of the build file is:

```
# $buildTools is the path to MSBuild.exe
# $solution is the path to the project's .sln file
& $buildTools $solution /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release,Platform=x86
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
  Write-Host 'Build completed successfully!'
} else {
  Write-Host '##vso[task.logissue type=error;]There were errors during the build of the application'
}
```

## Problem

Currently, `$LASTEXITCODE` can either be `0 (no errors)` or `1 (error)`. If the exit code is 0 everything is okay and Azure shows the green, passing badge; if it is 1 Azure shows the red, error badge. However, when there are warnings in the build they are shown in the logs and Azure shows the green badge.

## Goal

My goal is to make Azure display a yellow/orange warning badge when there are warnings. Is this possible and how? Thank you very much for your time!

## Attempted solution

In the C# project properties the `Warning level` is set to `4`; so I tried this modification to the power shell script, however, it did not work out.

```
& $buildTools $solution 4> 'warning.txt'
```

## Update with solution

Thanks to [D.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53374197/8737022)! The final build line looks like:

```
# $warningsFile is a path to a file that will contain all the warnings
& $buildTools $solution /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release,Platform=x86 /fl1 "/flp1:$warningsFile;warningsonly"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2017#save-the-log-output-to-multiple-files and write all warnings into a logfile, then check if the log file contains anything and  then write the warnings to the output using theese commands (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: Thank you for giving me hope! I've changed the build line to 
`& $buildTools $solution /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release,Platform=x86  /fl1 /flp1:warningsonly;logfile=$warningsFile` 
where `$warningsFile` is the path to a file in the same directory. This line however, throws the following error: 
`The term 'logfile=$warningsFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...` What would you recommend me to try next?

Comment: wrap your list of arguments with "

Comment: It does not work at all when I wrap the arguments with `"`, even if I remove the `/fl /flp` part it throws an error because of the `"`.

Comment: I found a solution! If I only wrap the `/fl /flp` part with `"` it works as expected. Thank you again!